# display avatar for authors without post in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

How can I get avatar for authors who haven't post any content yet.
I have created a specific page for each author which shows the author s posts like a blog.
But for those with no post, WordPress display a default avatar instead of user s chosen profile picture.
here is my code for author`s info:

```
<?php
$curauth = (isset($_GET['author_name'])) ? get_user_by('slug', $author_name) : get_userdata(intval($author));
?>

<div class="nauthor-brief" style="">
    <?php echo get_avatar( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ) , 60 ); ?>
    <div class="nauthor-brief-text">
    <h2> <?php echo $curauth->display_name; ?></h2>
    <p id="nauthor-description"><?php echo $curauth->user_description; ?></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1:** Log into your WordPress Dashboard

**Step 2:** In the left menu, under "Appearance", click "Editor"

**Step 3:** On the "Editor" page, find and click "content.php" in the list of files on the right of the page

**Step 4:** Find this section of code:

```
<div class="entry-meta">
<?php twentyeleven_posted_on(); ?>
</div><!-- .entry-meta -->
```

... and replace it with this:

```
<div class="entry-meta">
  <? echo get_avatar( get_the_author_meta('user_email'), $size = '50'); ?>
```

That's it, you're done! In this tutorial we placed the author's avatar at the top of the post (for the homepage). If you'd like show the author's avatar from anywhere else within the post (or on other pages), simply use the following code:

```
<? echo get_avatar( get_the_author_meta('user_email'), $size = '50'); ?>
```